# Spring Cloud Stream Funcation receives data that cannot be stored in database and has no transactions

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

**Spring Cloud Stream Funcation receives data that cannot be stored in database and has no transactions**

for example :

```java
    @Bean
    public Consumer<OrderCreateEvent> receiveOrderCreateEvent(){
        return order -> {
            System.out.println("OrderCreateEvent: "+order.getId());
            final OrderStream orderStream = new OrderStream();
            orderStream.setId(order.getId());
            orderService.save(orderStream); //FIXME Can't save data
        };
    }
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: orderService.save(orderStream); //FIXME Can't save data

Comment: I am sorry, but your are not helping. There is absolutely no way to know what your application is doing, what orderService is, what exception you are getting as you are refusing to provide any relevant information. I see you are a new user, so please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask